# jquery .sortable() serialize method onload

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the sortable serialize that saves the order to a database, which woks fine when the list i am sorting changes (i.e. dragged). However I want to auto serialize the order of the items on page load.

I am using the following to sort the data:

```
$(".menuSubSection_"+ <? echo $id; ?> +" ul.sortableSub").sortable({
                connectWith: "ul.sortableSub",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                update: function(){
                $('#saved').html('ORDER CHANGED + SAVED');
                $('#saved').fadeIn( function(){
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
                });
                saveOrderSub('<? echo $id; ?>');

                },
                start: function(event, ui) {
                $('ul.sortableSub').find('li:hidden').show();

                }
});
});
```

And the following function to store the serialize to database:

```
function saveOrderSub(menuid){

       var order = $(".menuSubSection_"+ menuid +" ul.sortableSub").sortable("serialize"); //
       $.post("../lib/saveOrderSub.php?menuID=" + menuid ,order,function(theResponse){

               $('#saved').html(theResponse);
               $('#saved').fadeIn( function(){
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
               }); 
                //reloadMenu();
                reloadMenuNav();
                     });
       event.preventDefault();
}
```

I have tried adding the `saveOrderSub(menuid)` to the header section so its called on load, however the serialise and post do not seem to work.

Can anyone shed any light on how i get this feature to work without changing the list order to trigger the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [jQuery UI Sortable API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-create) you can find an event called "create". The docu says that this **event is triggered when the sortable is created**. 
Maybe this could help you?
I think with your current implementation it would just look like this:

```
$(".menuSubSection_"+ <? echo $id; ?> +" ul.sortableSub").sortable({
            connectWith: "ul.sortableSub",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            //new
            create: saveOrderSub('<? echo $id; ?>'),
            update: function(){
            $('#saved').html('ORDER CHANGED + SAVED');
            $('#saved').fadeIn( function(){
            $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(); 
            });
            saveOrderSub('<? echo $id; ?>');

            },
            start: function(event, ui) {
            $('ul.sortableSub').find('li:hidden').show();

            }
});
```

Comment: That totally worked and you are my absolute hero thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (anywhere after jQuery):

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    saveOrderSub('<? echo $id; ?>');
  });
</script>
```